# PHP: Issues reading and writing data(with special characters) to file

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters, json

I am having issues reading-writing data(with special-characters) to file.

I am doing something like this:

```
//Writing data..
<?php
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

   $file = 'filename.db';
   $data = 'Some string with special characters';

   //Writing to the file..
   @file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));

?>
```

This works fine.
When I open the db file in Notepad ++, the data is proper.
Special characters are also stored properly:

```
 //Reading data..
 <?php
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

   $file = 'filename.db';

   //Reading from the file..
   $data = file_get_contents($file);
   $data = json_decode(utf8_encode(stripslashes($data)));

   echo $data;

 ?>
```

This displays the special characters as "????" or sometimes like "u00cf" or some other characters.

What is going wrong, and where?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: In UTF-8, a byte with the value 0xcf is a "continuation byte", i.e. part of the tail of a multibyte sequence, which suggests that the UTF-8 is at some point not interpreted as such. It would help if you could provide the exact string and the exact content of the file, because "special-characters" could mean different things to you than to the rest of us here. Lastly, what is the encoding of your PHP sourcefile? PHP treats strings as bytes, so it doesn't care whether it's UTF-8 or Latin-1, but things like utf8_encode() only do the right thing if their expected input matches.

Comment: Just stop unnecessarily messing up your data with stripslashes and utf8_encode.

Comment: thank you for your valuable comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're not storing arrays or other complex data structures you do not need JSON.
2. When reading from the file, why in god's name do you mistreat the data by stripping slashes and running it through `utf8_encode`? That's what's destroying the JSON format and thereby your data.

Just write the raw string into a file and read it back as is, done!

```
$string = 'ユーティーエッフエイト';
file_put_contents('file.txt', $string);
$string = file_get_contents('file.txt');
```

Nothing more you need to do.

Comment: What if I want to store the data in json format? Suppose I make a call to the PHP file to store the data. And I making the call from a different PHP file or from any other platform like say Adobe FLEX. And I send the data in JSON format. I am working with complex data-structures. In that case what should I do?

Comment: Then `json_encode` and `json_decode` it, **without any of the other nonsense** you did.

Answer (score 0):

In data reading script, try:

> $data = json_decode(mb_convert_encoding(stripslashes($data),
>   "UTF-8"));

Comment: Please explain the reason of down voting. Thank you.